# n-th child problems in IE9

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, internet-explorer-9

I've been heavily customising CSS on a page for a system we don't have full access to (e.g. we can't get into the head tag to edit things/change the meta information for example). Most things have turned out OK but I'm having problems hiding some stuff in IE9 using a hack I read about (works fine on Chrome) -

```
body > div.page-content-outer > div > form > div > table > tbody > tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr + tr > td > table > tbody > tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr {
  display:none;
}
```

I know this hack *should* work in IE9, but it doesn't.

The doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`.

Any hints or tips at what I might do would be greatly appreciated!

HTML -

```
<body>
<div class="page-content-outer">
    <div class="page-content-inner">

<form>
    <div class="content-outer">

        <table class="content-inner">

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                ...
                </tr>
                <tr>
                ...
                </tr>
                <tr>
                ...
                </tr>
                <tr>
                ...
                </tr>
                <tr valign="middle">
                    <td colspan="2" class="one" align="left">
                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                ...
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                ...
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="selected">
                            ...
                            <tr>
                                <!-- here -->
                                <td class="cardlabel" align="center">
                                    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3" border="0">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top"><input
<br><span >stuff</span></td>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top"><input
<br><span >stuff</span></td>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top"><input
<br><span >stuff</span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

Test A

```
body > div.page-content-outer > div > form > div > table > tbody > tr:first-child + tr + tr > td > table > tbody > tr:first-child > td.one.width190 > span {
display: none !important;
}
```

Thanks
MK

Comment: What do you mean by "works fine on Chrome" and "this hack should work in IE9"? Do you want IE9 to apply this rule or not? Looking at what you have, it doesn't look like a hack to me, but in fact a selector that IE9 should understand. Perhaps you should show us the entire hierarchy of this element starting from the body element.

Comment: So the element I want to hide seems to display:none fine in Chrome using that CSS. Hack was probably the wrong word, yes IE9 should understand it. I've included the hierarchy above. In actual fact it'd be great to pick and choose hiding the td elements with "stuff" written in them.

Comment: I wonder if IE9 imposes a limit on the length of a selector as well along with its "number of selectors" limit. Does shortening the selector result in any matches (doesn't matter if they over-match at this point)?

Comment: I think you could be onto something, I tried "Test A" (have pasted this into original comment) which worked to hide an element in IE9, but still no luck with the longer selectors (which work in other browsers).